# 'About' Page list of moderators needs to be updated

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, tour

The new SO mods should be added to the page on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about).

[image: Missing Mods]

Comment: Meta's own Tom Ritter is not even on there.

Comment: @random Good call.  I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to change it so that current moderators are listed automatically instead of a static webpage (as it appears to be the case).

Otherwise we'll have the same problem next time there are new moderators.

Comment: The only problem is that it puts way more stress on the server to dynamically create that page.  The mods don't change often enough for that.

Comment: Hey guys, how about having our cake and eating it, too. Just set up a cronjob to keep the page up-to-date.

Comment: @Justin: and it is also almost never seen.

Comment: @Justin - I can't see how it'd be much of a strain - it's not static now anyway (e.g. rep scores look up-to-date), and as @Koper says, I imagine the view count is very low.

Comment: @Dominic Technically the page is static, but the user flair that gets called is dynamic.  But, you all have valid points.  I just thing that making the whole page dynamic is a waste of time.  I'd rather have them work on building an API.

Comment: As you predicted, we have the same problem now that there are new moderators: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44455/moderator-list-on-metas-about-page-is-out-of-date