# Moderator list on Meta's "about" page is out of date

Tags: support, status-completed, tour

**Please read before voting to close as dup.** [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39450/about-page-list-of-moderators-needs-to-be-updated) is an earlier instance of the same problem. I don't think this should be closed as dup because new changes have taken place since then, even though the old question is closed [status-complete]. (I'm also not sure why that was marked complete if Jonathan and Gumbo were not added to the list.)

The list of moderators on [Meta's "about" page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) is out of date.

- Diago is still listed.
- Jonathan Sampson is not listed.
- Gumbo is not listed.
- random is not listed (not yet a mod on meta).
- quack quixote is not listed (not yet a mod on meta).

> **Related:**
>   [‘About’ Page list of moderators needs to be updated.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39450/about-page-list-of-moderators-needs-to-be-updated)

Comment: FWIW... quack and random aren't mods on Meta yet.

Comment: @Arjan Random and quack haven't been moderators yet here on Meta.

Comment: Do they need to be? It's not like there is a lack of moderators here. I realize that - so far - every moderator on any of the official websites is a moderator here too, but I question the reasoning behind that decision

Comment: I agree @kop, We should have different moderators per site... meta is a site by itself and should have its own set of moderators

Comment: I refer you to the Meta FAQ: *Any community moderator from Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User is also a moderator here.* If they are moderators elsewhere, the FAQ indicates they are automatically moderators on Meta and thus should be listed.

Comment: Then the FAQ needs reviewing

Comment: @Downvoter (and others closing as dup): is there a better way to report a problem when it previously existed and was fixed and marked completed, but now it has returned?  closing it reduces the chance the team will see it.

Comment: @Kip: well, I guess when random and quack are made moderators, they can edit the status-complete tag out of that previous question... ;-)

Comment: Maybe putting the "Please read..." message first will work? :)